# Jframe is not showing up

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I'm having problems creating a JFrame in my application, so  I tried to run the simplest code I could in order to locate what was happening.

```
public class prueba {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       JFrame f = new JFrame("Primer JFrame");
        f.add(new JLabel("Intenteu tancar per la creueta..."));

        f.setSize(800,600);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

I'm astounded, this does nothing, but this code is re-used from another project in which everything goes OK. This doesen't create the JFrame and I only get this in the console as response:

> C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: -1073740791

Comment: This is some problem with your netbeans configuration, the code you've posted works fine (when you fix the syntax errors, which you should edit your question to do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an error when running this program also:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       EXIT_ON_CLOSE cannot be resolved to a variable

But when I deleted this line:

```
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

It ran fine, but when the window was exited, the program did not quit right away. So you can either delete this line, or if you want the program to terminate right after window is closed, extend JFrame, and use a constructor, like this:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class prueba extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public prueba() {
        add(new JLabel("Intenteu tancar per la creueta..."));
        setTitle("Primer JFrame");
        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new prueba();
     }
 }
```

Comment: I believe someone down-voted it because the error you received is not the same as Asdemuertes and so you have not actually answered his question. His error message shows a problem with netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

I get issues like these in Netbeans all the time. (Frankly, I'm considering switching IDEs).
There's no guarantee if these suggestions will work, but it's worth a shot. One of these usually fixes my issues.

1. The usual solution is to clean and build your project, as sometimes Netbeans will compile older code instead. Do this by clicking on "Run", then "Clean and build main project", then try running it again.
2. Sometimes a simple close-and-reboot Netbeans will fix this issue.
3. If neither of the above two work, I just make a new class and copy/paste the code into it, then delete the older class. This is usually a "hard-fix" for me, although it can be tedious.

Comment: That is very interesting i have never encountered any problems with netbeans. What version are you using?

Comment: there is also incorrect code which needs to be fixed, so if he does all of this, the program will still not run correctly.

Comment: Hmm... I have always used Version 8.1 (windows 8.1) and never had any problems, perhaps there is a bug with the newest release, or a compatibility issue with windows 10?

Comment: Perhaps. I'm not certain. I'm taking a programming course in college and everyone in my class is using the same version of Netbeans. Some people have no issues at all, others have even worse issues. I know someone whose Netbeans IDE crashes for them daily.

Comment: I'm also working with netbeans 8.2 and windows 10. A. Cucci  I tried your fixes, but still didn't work out.

Comment: @A.Cucci - In that case it is most likely OS related, are all the others using windows 10?